# Can't connect Release Management client for Visual Studio to VSTS

Tags: ms-release-management, azure-devops

I want to test Microsoft Release Management with Visual Studio Online.

I installed release management client for visual studio 2013. Installation worked fine but I was unable to configure it and always get the error message at start:

"*current client version is not compatible. You must upgrade the client*"

I installed update 4 that is the latest version for VS 2013.

So I don't understand what I can do.

Does anybody solved this issue?
It is also unclea for me with what the client is not compatible because this happend with VSO ou TFS 2013 as well

thank

Comment: Did you install Release Management for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 with Update 4to work with VS 2013 Update 4?

Answer (score 0):

It's suggested to use the new features from the **Release** hub in your account. 
The release templates and releases data that you create in WPF client will not be migrated to the new vNext service. The two services (RM client + RM service and vNext RM services) will co-exist until **March 1st 2016**. You will have to re-create your release definitions using the web interface before that time.

Comment: Ok, thank you


But what about TFS on premise? In fact I choose VSTS in order not to have to bother me to build a TFS server

Comment: You can maintain your own on-premises Release Management server to work with TFS on premise.

Comment: I installed a TFS 2015 server with RM.

I was enable to run the WPF client from within the server, but I got the same error message from my local computer.

I can access without any problem on:

http://<SERVER>:1000/ReleaseManagement

Comment: Did you install Release Management for Visual Studio 2015 at website: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48153? Release Management for Visual Studio 2015 requires Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 or Test Professional 2015, please check your VS version too.

Answer (score -1):

VSTS Release Management doesn't support the Release Management client (WPF client). You have to use the web interface.